# Mule Proxying SOAP Service with API Manager

Tags: mule

I'm trying to proxy an HTTPS SOAP service in mule, so used API manager in anypoint and given the wsdl url there, but while deploying the application I'm getting errors as follows

```
Could not resolve placeholder 
'wsdl(p['wsdl.uri']).services[0].preferredPort.addresses[0].host' 
    in string value "<http:request-config name="http-request-config" 
    host="![wsdl(p['wsdl.uri']).services[0].preferredPort.addresses[0].host]" 
    port="![wsdl(p['wsdl.uri']).services[0].preferredPort.addresses[0].port]" protocol="HTTPS">
    </http:request-config>
```

I've downloaded the project and **wsdl.uri** property exists in properties file.

**UPDATE:**

Just to get an idea of what the wsdl function returns I tried giving the following dataweave in a sample project.

```
#[dw(wsdl('https://myhost/check/checkrecieveAPI?WSDL'))]
```

But received the following error as TLS is not configured. Not sure how to configure TLS in **wsdl** function.

> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: Let us know if you found below answer helpful to resolve the issue..

Answer (score 1):

There are two different issues.

**1.You are not able to read the properties from property file.**

**Answer** :You need to load the property file into context by using spring context tag.

eg:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="propetyFileName.properties" />
<flow name="myProject_flow">
<logger message="${propertyFromPropertyFile}" doc:name="System Property 
 Set in Property File"/>
</flow>
```

Refer [link](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/configuring-properties) for more details.

**2.SSL handshake exception.**

**Answer:**

You are getting this exception,because you are trying to access a protected resource ,and for this resource you are not having a valid certificate added to you JDK.

For this ,check the JDK that is configured in your mule/anypoint studio.

You will need to import the required certificate into your JDK.

There are several ways you can do this.Below is one of the approach I use,

When your Java program attempts to connect to a server that has an invalid or self signed certificate, such as an application server in a development environment, you may get the following exception:

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

To make your Java runtime environment trust the certificate, you need to import it into the JRE certificate store.

Step 1 - Get the certificate into your browser store

Browse to your application server using SSL. Your browser will tell you that the certificate isn't trusted and allow you to trust it, thereby placing it in the browser certificate store.

Step 2 - Export the certificate to a binary file

Your browser will have some kind of certificate manager that allows you to export or back up specific certificates to binary files. In Firefox that would be under Preferences / Advanced / Encryption / Servers. Find the certificate presented by the server and export it as a binary DER file.

Step 3 - Import the certificate into the Java Store

Make sure you have write access to your JRE and  use the keytool utility to import it:

keytool -import -alias alias -keystore path-to-jre/lib/security/cacerts -file path-to-certificate-file

Example:

keytool -import -alias newCert -keystore /opt/jdk1.6/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file /home/newCert.der

You will be prompted for the keystore password, which is by default changeit.

**OR**

You can use a utility java based tool to do it easily.Check below link.
https://github.com/escline/InstallCert

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply Mahesh. For answer 1 - I'm not building the project, its mule anypoint API itself is creating the project with those properties, also for answer 2- I cant have the keystore in my local instead I use TLS insecure as true for all the https connections. so my doubt here is how do I configure the tls inside wsdl('url') dataweave function or is there any other way to create the HTTPS proxy service

Answer (score 0):

To configure TLS in wsdl function.
The TLS Configuration element is independent of any module or transport. In Mule 3.7 onwards, it’s supported both by the HTTP Connector and in the Web Service Consumer.

You can create this element through the UI of the HTTP Connector’s Global configuration element, on the TLS/SSL tab, or through the UI of the Web Service Consumer, on the Security tab.

The tls:context element defines a configuration for TLS, which can be used from both the client and server sides. It can be referenced by other configuration objects of other modules (or defined as a nested element of one of them).

Inside it, you can include two nested elements: key-store and trust-store. You don’t need to include both, but at least one of the two must be present:

From the server side: the trust store contains certificates of the trusted clients, the key store contains the private and public key of the server.

From the client side: the trust store contains certificates of the trusted servers, the key store contains the private and public key of the client.

Adding a trust store or a key store to a TLS configuration implicitly implements the corresponding kind of authentication. Adding both a keystore and a trust store to one same config (as in the code example above) implicitly implements two way TLS authentication, also known as mutual authentication.